# Returning the number of checkboxes that are checked via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Currently having some trouble in terms of filtering out checkboxes that have been checked.

```
var checkboxControl = $("#builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr");
var isChecked = checkboxControl.find('.control')
console.log(isChecked);
```

the console returns all the checkboxes in an array. If i break it down in the google developer tools, i can find what boxes are checked and what isnt.[image]

I then try the following code to try n filter only the checkboxes that have a "true" value.

```
isChecked.prop('checked',true); 
console.log(isChecked);
```

but no luck. This returns all the checkboxes still.

Comment: If you want to retrieve if the checkbox is checked you need to do ***.prop("checked")***. If you do ***.prop("checked", true)*** it will set the checked value of the checkbox to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` will get you all checked checkboxes

for a specific class you can do this:

`$('input.yourclass[type=checkbox]:checked')`

Answer (score 0):

Get value of all checked Checkbox.

```
var value = "";
$(".SelectItem:checked").each(function () {

        if (value == "")
            value = $(this).val();
        else
            value += "," + $(this).val();

});
```